# First month number in a loop not being converted to a month name?

Tags: php, loops, oop

I am developing a small school management system that requires me to store tuition fee installments into the database. Each installment has a due date and based on the due date I convert the month number into a month name.

The code works perfectly fine however I've noticed that the first month number extracted from the first due date is not passing through my function that converts it to a month name. All the following month numbers have no issue, it is just the first one in the loop.

My function for adding installments is this one:

```
public function addInstallments($prepInt){

    //extraction converted variables
    extract($prepInt);

    //divide total fee by the number of installments to get the value of the installments
    $monthly_fee = round($fees/$number_of_installments,2);

    /*
    Retrieve course id of course
    */
    $model = new CoursesModel();
    $course_id = $model->returnCourseId($code);


    /*
    Save course start date in the due date array because it is going to be the base period for the due date calculations
    */
    $due_date[0] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$start_date"));//base date for due date calculations


    //save each installment into the database
    for($i=1;$i<=$number_of_installments;$i++){


        //add 30 days to course start date
        $due_date[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("".$due_date[$i-1]." +30 days"));

        //retrieve month name and year from due date
        $month_int = date("m",strtotime($due_date[$i]));    
        $year = date("Y",strtotime($due_date[$i]));
        $month_name = $this->returnNameofMonth($month_int);

        $fieldset = "`course_id`='$course_id',`name`='Propina de $month_name $year',`amount_per_installment`='$monthly_fee',`due_date`='$due_date[$i]'";

        $status = $model->CreateDb('installments',$fieldset); 

    }

    return $status;
```

And this is my function for converting the month numbers into month names

```
/*
    Returns name of the months
    */

    public function returnNameofMonth($month_int){

        switch($month_int){
             case 01:
              return 'Janeiro';
              break;
             case 02:
              return 'Fevereiro';
              break;
             case 03:
              return 'Março';
              break;
             case 04:
              return 'Abril';
              break;
             case 05:
              return 'Maio';
              break;
             case 06:
              return 'Junho';
              break;
             case 07:
              return 'Julho';
              break;
             case 08:
              return 'Agosto';
              break;
             case 09:
              return 'Setembro';
              break;
             case 10:
              return 'Outobro';
              break;
             case 11:
              return 'Novembro';
              break;
             case 12:
              return 'Dezembro';
              break;
        }
    }
```

N.B. Am using OOP

When I did some debugging on my own I discovered two things:

1. When I don't convert the month numbers into month names the month number of the first element of my loop is stored in my database;
2. The first element of the loop is unable to pass through my `returnNameOfMonth()`.

I did a second test of my code  with some slight change in my `addInstallments()` function. With the new change I discovered that the function saved 'teste' as a month name in the database without any issues.

```
        /*
    Add installments 
    */
    public function addInstallments($prepInt){

        //extraction converted variables
        extract($prepInt);

        //divide total fee by the number of installments to get the value of the installments
        $monthly_fee = round($fees/$number_of_installments,2);

        /*
        Retrieve course id of course
        */
        $model = new CoursesModel();
        $course_id = $model->returnCourseId($code);


        /*
        Save course start date in the due date array because it is going to be the base period for the due date calculations
        */
        $due_date[0] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$start_date"));//base date for due date calculations


        //save each installment into the database
        for($i=1;$i<=$number_of_installments;$i++){


            //add 30 days to course start date
            $due_date[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("".$due_date[$i-1]." +30 days"));

            //retrieve month name and year from due date
            $month_int = date("m",strtotime($due_date[$i]));    
            $year = date("Y",strtotime($due_date[$i]));
            //this is the slight change I added
            if($i==1){
                $month_name = 'teste';
            }
            else{
              $month_name = $this->returnNameofMonth($month_int);
            }

            $fieldset = "`course_id`='$course_id',`name`='Propina de $month_name $year',`amount_per_installment`='$monthly_fee',`due_date`='$due_date[$i]'";

            $status = $model->CreateDb('installments',$fieldset); 

}

        return $status;
    }
```

Conclusion. The problem seems to lie on my `returnNameOfMonth()` function but up to now I can't seem to figure out what is the issue.

Comment: The `returnNameOfMonth()` function works just fine. Check the value of `$month_int` you are passing to it.

Comment: @VicenteOlivertRiera I did a debugging of my `$month_int` and its working perfectly. When I store the month number directly into database instead of the names, even the first month number in the loop is saved so thats why I said am confused on whats causing my problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need mount in m format ('01' .. '02')  you shold use string for avoid implict conversion .. then  try

```
     switch($month_int){
         case '01':
          return 'Janeiro';
          break;
         case '02':
          return 'Fevereiro';
         ....
```

otherwise th could be implicitally converted  in

```
switch($month_int){
         case 1:
          return 'Janeiro';
          break;
         case 2:
          return 'Fevereiro';
          ...
```

Comment: Good suggestion but a lot of work just to get the month name IMO :)

Comment: Thanks for your tip, when I implemented this change my problem got solved :-). I did multiple tests to verify that the problem was gone and all were successful.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify your returnNameofMonth function or even remove it completely and just use date to derive the full name of the month. If you want to keep the function try:

```
/*
Returns name of the months
*/

public function returnNameofMonth($month_int){

return date('F',strtotime($month_int . '/01' . date('Y') . '/'));
```

You could also use it directly in the addInstallments function:

```
$month_name = date('F',strtotime($month_int . '/01' . date('Y') . '/'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Dave. The problem is that I need the name of months in portuguese and not English. If it weren't for that I was not going to be using my custom function for converting the month numbers to month names, @Dave

Comment: The language the months are returned in is not related to the function. See the PHP setlocale function for how to localize the names in the language you desire. http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: Thanks :-) @Dave, I went with your suggestion and know I am able to do the conversion of month numbers to names using this 2 lines of code.                                                                                                    `//set local to portuguese
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');                  //retrieve month name and year from due date
$month_name =  ucfirst(strftime("%B", strtotime($due_date[$i])));    `